# Converts a linear range of values to an exponential range of values

Tags: c++, math

Im looking how to convert a linear range of values (0-127) that comes from GUI slider to an exponential range (25.623-401.31) into c++ environment for audio purpose.

This method using math.h it starts from the low value and calculate four octaves above

```
value = ldexp(25.623, value * 4 / 127);
```

higher value: 409.968

I can reduce the higher value to reach the target one by:

```
value = ldexp(25.623, value * 3.915525114155252 / 127);
```

I wonder to know other ways to do it, focussing on the lowest amount of effort for CPU

Comment: This seems more like a [math.se] problem. Once you determine the appropriate equation, implementing it in C++ should be obvious.

Comment: I don't think there's much you can do about the CPU use. This is going to require floating point exponentiation or logarithms.

Comment: `ldexp` is taking `int` as its second parameter. Trying to put a floating point type there is probably not precise enough.

Comment: I think the function you want is `pow()`.

Comment: Precalculate all 128 values in advance using your favorite algorithm and put them into array. Access the array when needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a geometric sequence, so you need only compute the common ratio r between successive levels:

high = low.r<sup>N-1</sup>

whence

r = (high/low)<sup>1/(N-1)</sup>

so you only need a single call to pow() and N-1 multiplies to preset your levels.

In code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   const int N = 128;
   const double low  = 25.623;
   const double high = 401.31;

   double r = pow( high / low, 1.0 / ( N - 1.0 ) );
   
   double levels[N];
   levels[0] = low;
   for ( int i = 1; i < N; i++ ) levels[i] = levels[i-1] * r;
   levels[N-1] = high;       // avoid cumulative floating-point error

   // Check
   cout << "Linear" << '\t' << "Exponential" << '\n';
   for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) cout << i << '\t' << levels[i] << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
Linear  Exponential
0       25.623
1       26.1841
2       26.7576
3       27.3435
4       27.9424
5       28.5543
6       29.1796
7       29.8186
8       30.4717
9       31.139
10      31.8209
11      32.5178
12      33.2299
...
lots more lines
...
124     376.058
125     384.294
126     392.71
127     401.31
```

Comment: thank you @lastchance, this answer my question, and how to spread the values on a logarithmic growth? essentially to obtain the inverse of exponential you explained

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean by the question. The inverse operation sadly needs logs each time: y = a.log(x)+b, where x is the linear scale, y is the logarithmic scale. a and b come from fitting the two ends (1 and 2), giving a=(y2-y1)/log(x2/x1) and b=y2-a.log(x2). You can use any base of logarithms you like ... as long as you are consistent.